# ORA-04098: trigger 'SYSTEM.TEXT_TRIG' is invalid and failed re-validation

Tags: sql, database, oracle, triggers

I am using the oracle database 10g express edition to execute triggers. My table structure is as shown below:

Table text:

```
create table text
(
    tid number Not Null,
    tname varchar2(5)
);
```

Table book:

```
create table book
(
    bid number Not Null,
    bname varchar2(5),
    foreign key(bid) references text(tid)
);
```

Later inserted one row in text tabe: 1,abc

My question is when i am about to insert a value to text table, it should automatically insert a value in book table.

I had created a trigger named text_trig: structure is a s follows:

```
create trigger text_trig after insert on text
for each row
begin
     insert into book set bid=NEW.tid;
end;
/
```

It gave me an warning message saying: Trigger created with compilation errors.

when I inserted a new value in text table, it is showing an error message as

> trigger 'SYSTEM.TEXT_TRIG' is invalid and failed re-validation.

Answer (score 0):

You missed a colon.

```
set bid = :NEW.tid
```